# how to set few forms in CF7 to submit with one click and no reload?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

i got a page i want to contain the same form 10 times, and at the bottom one button to send all of them instantly with no reload between them.
im doing so because i need it to create 10 new rows in the DB instead of one line, since its 10 different enteries.

so my solution for that was to have duplication's of the form and just submit them with one click.

now im encountering an issue, because im trying to submit them using JS but for example it only submits the last one and reloads the page.

```js
<script>       
    function send() {
        document.getElementById("form-1").submit(); 
        document.getElementById("form-2").submit();   
        document.getElementById("form-3").submit();
    }   
</script>
```

```html
<button id="submit-all" name="submit-all" onclick="send()">send them all!</button>
```

with this code, the issue is that only the last form is being submitted and that it refreshes the page.

any idea how to fix it? 
or maybe, any idea how to approach my original issue that i need a form to create few rows if possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Submitting a form always loads a new document. You've to send the data by using AJAX.

Comment: Ok, then i need to create an ajax command that works with the CF7 system... any idea where i can find a guide / guidance / files that can help me with it? il start digging the source files of CF7 but im sure il get lost pretty quickly

Comment: Why can't you create one form, but loop through submissions and foreach create db row?